# set EXPECT_CALL to redirect the call to the original method

Tags: googlemock

I have a class with several methods that depend on each other. Lets say foo(), bar() and baz().

When I test bar() I need to mock the behavior of foo(), when I test baz() I need to mock the behavior of bar().

If I mock bar for baz I cannot use the same mock class to test bar with the mocked foo().

My question is can I set EXPECT_CALL to actually call the original behavior and how. This will eliminate the need to create several Mock classes.

Answer (score 13):

Answer can be found in [gMock Cookbook](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#delegating-calls-to-a-parent-class).

In short, you need to write

```cpp
class MockFoo : public Foo {
public:
  // Mocking a pure method.
  MOCK_METHOD(void, Pure, (int n), (override));
  // Mocking a concrete method.  Foo::Concrete() is shadowed.
  MOCK_METHOD(int, Concrete, (const char* str), (override));
};
```

and

```cpp
ON_CALL(foo, Concrete).WillByDefault([&foo](const char* str) {
  return foo.Foo::Concrete(str);
});
```

or

```cpp
EXPECT_CALL(foo, Concrete).WillOnce([&foo](const char* str) {
  return foo.Foo::Concrete(str);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without adding any extra methods, with an unusual call syntax: `obj.Parent::method()` or `ptr->Parent::method()`.

For example:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    virtual int bar() const { return 42; }
};

struct MockFoo : public Foo
{
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(bar, int());
};

TEST(Demo, mock_can_call_parent)
{
    MockFoo mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, bar()).WillOnce([&mock](){ 
        return mock.Foo::bar(); // trick is here
    });

    EXPECT_EQ(mock.bar(), 42);
}
```